# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ApplicationException' occurred in RDotNet.NativeLibrary.dll

Tags: c#, .net, r, interop

I'm looking into using R.NET for working with R library in my .NET application. 
I have installed the libraries and the R environment.

However, i get the exception described above when running the sample program provided on the project page:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

         //   REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(); // <-- May be omitted; the next line would call it.
            REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
            // A somewhat contrived but customary Hello World:
            CharacterVector charVec = engine.CreateCharacterVector(new[] { "Hello, R world!, .NET speaking" });
            engine.SetSymbol("greetings", charVec);
            engine.Evaluate("str(greetings)"); // print out in the console
            string[] a = engine.Evaluate("'Hi there .NET, from the R engine'").AsCharacter().ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("R answered: '{0}'", a[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit the program");
            Console.ReadKey();
            engine.Dispose();
        }
```

In case anyone has run into this issue, i would be really glad to have any comments. I have searched relevant forum but no luck yet.

full exception information:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ApplicationException' occurred in RDotNet.NativeLibrary.dll
Additional information: Windows Registry key 'SOFTWARE\R-core' not found in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE nor HKEY_CURRENT_USER**

I checked the R is properly installed and R-Core is found HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please report the full error message of the exception, if any. If this ApplicationException is thrown by R.NET, it will have a message, and very likely something about Windows registry keys. If this is the case, diagnose the issue further using the code sample in http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/ts_paths_on_windows/

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ApplicationException' occurred in RDotNet.NativeLibrary.dll

Additional information: Windows Registry key 'SOFTWARE\R-core' not found in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE nor HKEY_CURRENT_USER . I checked that the keys are there. R is properly installed on my machine

Comment: Please follow the diagnosis instructions in  http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/ts_paths_on_windows/ . This would help isolate the issue. I suspect a mismatch between 32 and 64 bits in your c# project and R set up (which R engine did you install: 32 and/or 64 bits?) but this is just a wild guess without the aforementioned diagnosis.

Comment: I have windows 7 64 bits so i installed the 64 bits version. Thanks, i will try the diagnosis

Comment: this statement :"I suspect a mismatch between 32 and 64 bits in your c# project and R set up" was the key to the solution.  changed the target platform of my project and i was sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the diagnosis instructions in jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/ts_paths_on_windows . This would help isolate the issue. **I suspect a mismatch between 32 and 64 bits in your c# project and R set up** (which R engine did you install: 32 and/or 64 bits?) but this is just a wild guess without the aforementioned diagnosis.

Changing the target platform of my project solved the issue following the comment above